how to create desktop shortcut for file in ubuntu 24.04
use to be able to just open nautilus (files) and hold shift+ctrl and drag file to desktop to create a shortcut for it - now it just copies it... what the heck happened?!? How do I create a shortcut to a file for my desktop?
Apparently the answer is to just dump 24.04lts and replace it w/my 20.04lts image! Take about 20 minutes...(not an answer...)
"...creating a shortcut to perform some process on a specific file is not done that way in 22.04 nor in 24.04..." - WHY the HECK NOT!?! ('cause it's done a different way - see Talaat Etman's comment below! What a Guy!!!)

What's your GUI or, what's your flavor of Ubuntu - Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu . . .

ubuntu 24.04... like I said.

Your GUI would be gnome I think.  I've got Xubuntu which means the XFCE4 desktop where you can drag and drop files on the desktop however, creating a shortcut to perform some process on a specific fie is not done that way. in 22.04 nor in 24.04

also, using the wayland desktop, not X... and yes, the old method that worked well on my 18.04lts (shift-ctrl drag/drop) only copies the file :-\

from nautilus preferences select to activate create a link, right click on the file, creat a link, and move the linke to the desktop

not my answer - credit goes to Talaat Etman!

from nautilus preferences select to activate create a link, right click on the file, create a link, and move the link to the desktop – Talaat Etman's comment


If you are using Ubuntu 24.04 with Gnome Shell Version 46. This option is not to create a launcher or shortcut link from any of the file managers.
This method is to create a .desktop file in the proper format. Freedesktop sets that standard for the .desktop file. This link to the Desktop Entry Specification at Freedesktop.org is for the following .desktop file. This template.desktop LINK to the file template is a good starting point. After the creation of the file, the file must be given permission to launch. This can be done 2 ways.
Nautilus (Files): Right-click on the .desktop file, select “Properties”, and then click on the “Permissions” tab. Check the box next to “Allow executing file as program”.
Terminal: Use the chmod command to set the executable permission: chmod 755 Foo Viewer.desktop (replace Foo Viewer with the actual file name).
The Ubuntu distribution, uses freedesktop.org standards and specifications to ensure compatibility and consistency across different desktop environments, including GNOME.
First, is to create the file name, in this case we will use the example and name the file Foo Viewer.desktop. This file template will have the entry Name=Foo Viewer and this will be the name of the desktop when the proper permissions are provided, for the file to launch, the Foo Viewer program or link to some site.
You could use this following template this is the file mentioned in the above template link.
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Foo Viewer
Comment=The best viewer for Foo objects available!
TryExec=fooview
Exec=fooview %F
Icon=fooview
MimeType=image/x-foo;
Actions=Gallery;Create;

[Desktop Action Gallery]
Exec=fooview --gallery
Name=Browse Gallery

[Desktop Action Create]
Exec=fooview --create-new
Name=Create a new Foo!
Icon=fooview-new

GOOD LUCK!
